# Sink console output to .txt file from a function

Tags: r, dataframe, output, cat, sink

I need to populate a .txt file while running a code with nested functions. I use `sink()` for this purpose. The output consists of a) text messages, b) dataframe rows. I fail to print dataframes from inside the nested function:

```
sink("log.txt")

cat("Some message")          # Successfully prints to log.txt
head(some_df)                # Successfully prints to log.txt

some_fun = function(x){
    # ...
    cat("Another message")   # Successfully prints to log.txt
    head(another_df)         # Nothing gets printed to log.txt
    # check that another_df is not empty:
    cat(nrow(another_df))    # Successfully prints to log.txt (>0) 
    # ...
}
some_fun(x=0)

sink()
```

So what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Wrap `print` around `head` like this: `print(head(another_df))`  . It should work then..

Comment: And include `"\n"` as the last string in each `cat()`.

Comment: Many thanks @samadhi. I was an idiot and tried much more complex combinations of cat() and print().

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a `print` around `head` inside your function. Like this:

```
print(head(another_df))
```